# Show a few db results but then show all on click - advice

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a comments section on items a page, but this can get very long with many comments on some items.

What I want to do is show only first x results, then on click of a link e.g. View All I can show them all for the item (not all items).

Currently I use something like this:

```
$result350 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages where id=$id order by dateadded asc",$db);

echo '<div id="wallWall$id">';

    while($db88 = mysql_fetch_array($result350)){

        echo '<div class="msgs_row">
            <div class="msgs_pic">
                <img src="'.$db88[live_prof_pic].'">
            </div>
            <div class="msgs_comment">'
                .stripslashes($db88[comment]).
            '</div></div>';

    } 

    echo '</div>';
```

So, i could change the while loop to something like

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    echo ...
}
```

so I only display the first 4 but how would I then modify the display to show all?

Should I load the first 4 into one div and the rest into another which is hidden then just `$('#hiddenResults').show();` on click of the view all link or is there a better more efficient way to do this?

There could be as many 30 items on the page with comments under them.

Not sure which tags to use for this so will run with a couple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using LIMIT in the first query which fetches just 5 comments.

```
$result350 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages where id=$id order by dateadded asc LIMIT 5",$db);
```

On clicking link to load all comments, you can make an Ajax call to server which fetches all the comments (dont use LIMIT in the query this time or keep it high, say 50). then you can show all comments received in ajax response using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax solution is nice if you have a lot of additional comments to load. If it is not really that many (like 30 - 50) it could be better to do it the way you mentioned where they are sent with the original page, but in a hidden div.